# Limit of words in Phrase List

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am adding some keywords in phrase list, there are ~8000 words. Is there any limit in LUIS phrase list. As I am getting an error "BadArgument. Too many words in Data Dictionary".

Can anyone tell me what is the limit of phrase list words?

Also is there any other approach to incorporate these words?

Comment: Each list entity can hold [20,000 items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-entity-types#types-of-entities), and you can have up to 50 list entities which don't count towards your 30 entity limit. For your second question... It depends on how you're trying to use your list entity.  Can you take a screenshot of when you see that message?

Comment: Disregard my earlier comment here; I misread your question. Instead see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 10 *Phrase Lists* and the maximum length of each of these is 5,000 items. You can find the information [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-features#phrase-list-features) in the docs.

Regarding incorporating words, can you give an example of the words you're using?

Comment: Hi apologised for the late comment, I have a list of company names. Usually the company name is like XYZ Ltd or it can ab xyz Ltd. User can ask a query in multiple ways for ex they can use only xyz or they can use ab xyz or ab.